# select top 30 percent of the entries for each day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have table `sales` storing transactions for each day.

```
Date    Receipt Total
4/21/2018   325 600
4/21/2018   326 800
4/21/2018   327 500
4/21/2018   328 900
4/21/2018   329 500
4/26/2018   330 600
4/26/2018   331 1080
4/26/2018   332 1200
4/26/2018   333 1120
4/29/2018   334 600
4/29/2018   335 1400
5/1/2018    336 1500
5/1/2018    337 4000
5/1/2018    338 6000
```

From the above table, I need to select top 30 percent of the entries for each day and the table should look like the one below.

```
Date    Receipt Total
4/21/2018   325 600
4/21/2018   326 800
4/26/2018   330 600
4/26/2018   331 1080
4/29/2018   334 600
5/1/2018    336 1500
5/1/2018    337 4000
```

I have used the following code:

```
SELECT TOP 30 percent *       
FROM sales
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Total Desc

Comment: 1. Top 30 percent by what order? 2. What version of SQL Server are you using? ([edit] to add the version tag)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am using sql server 2016. I guess it has to be order by date

Comment: It can't be ordered by date - I mean, the end result might be ordered by date, but the top 30 percent has to be ordered by something else, like Total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with `partition by date` and check against the 30% number of total count of each day.

```
select date,receipt,total 
from   (select *, 
               ceiling(tc * 30.00 / 100.00) as under30 
        from   (select date, 
                       receipt, 
                       total, 
                       row_number() over(partition by date  order by (select null)) rn, 
                       count(*) over(partition by date order by (select null)) tc 
                from   sales) t
         ) t1 
where  rn <= under30
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YFUP4761)</kbd>**

**Output:**

```
+------------+---------+-------+
| date       | receipt | total |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-04-21 | 325     | 600   |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-04-21 | 326     | 800   |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-04-26 | 330     | 600   |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-04-26 | 331     | 1080  |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-04-29 | 334     | 600   |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2018-05-01 | 336     | 1500  |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

**Note:** If you want 30% of of total count in that case you need to change your count calculation logic like following in the above query.

```
  count(*) over(order by (select null)) tc
```

Comment: what is tc, t, t1 and rn?

Comment: tc is total count, rn is rownumber and t1 and t2 are just alisas names for tables. Is this query working for you?

Comment: @Sonam, I have updated the answer and demo by adding ceiling to the percentage calculation, you will get the output what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. You are the man. Cheers.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly with sql2016 but looks like it is having problem with sql2008express. Is there need to be code for sql2008 express?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't have a 2008 express available with me to test, but it should work, I suggest you take this query and raise a question for the same. I you wan to proceed with the same query, the row number part you can write as as sub query

Comment: try changing "order by (select null)" to "order by date"

Comment: Suggest you to raise another question mentioning the compatibility problem, you might get some help. I am also checking.. if I find anything I will let you know

Comment: It had to do with sql server version. I upgraded to sql server 2016 and the code works now. Thank you.